# Get the closest value of a column in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that have a CP value (numeric), for example, 28030, 28060, 27100 etc. And the user can introduce a number via PHP. I want to, having this number for example, 28050, order in MYSQL my table putting 28060 as the first position.

This is the basic of my table:

```
SELECT * FROM `tiendas` ORDER BY `CP`
```

Comment: I tried the function ABS but didn't worked

Comment: Did you try `SELECT * 
FROM tiendas 
ORDER BY abs(CP-28050)`

Comment: @Sergio Could you share your SQL using `ABS()`? What do you mean by "didn't worked"? Is there any syntax error? Or does the result differ from your expectation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ABS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) will work. Here's a query that does the job:

```
SELECT 
    CP
FROM tiendas
ORDER BY ABS(CP- 28050) ASC
```